# tcpdump: How do I suppress packet information?

Tags: tcpdump

When I kill a tcpdump process, I get the following three lines:

```
NN packets captured
NN packets received by filter
NN packets dropped by kernel
```

I am piping the output of tcpdump into a txt file and want to keep my terminal clean.
Is there a way to suppress this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322103/how-to-remove-tcpdump-first-and-last-lines), the `tcpdump` stats and header lines are a part of `stderr`. So, if you want to suppress this information *and* store the packet information in a file, you can do:

```
tcpdump 2> /dev/null > output.txt
```

Using `/dev/null/` [will discard the `stderr` output](https://linuxhint.com/what_is_dev_null/).